# Creating Layouts in Angular 2 projects

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi i am creating a project with angular 2. I want to have a number of layouts for my each modules like a Login Layout, Home Layout, and A user layout for every one who have logged in.

I can not attain this thing in my project. Right now i have created a page for each component by separating modules into different component that will be used again and again.

Can anyone help me out to create a layout like we have in

> CakePhp

for importing all stuffs once and just change a set of data with the change of route.

Layout Without login

```
<div> 
   <app-header-before-login> </app-header-before-login>
   <app-body> </app-body>
   <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

After login

```
<div> 
   <app-header> </app-header>
   <app-body> </app-body>
   <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

app-body content will be pulled from components as per routes. I just don't want to write these html in each components.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to switch between components:

1. Use for example [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html) to switch between the
   `<app-header></app-header>` and
   `<app-header-before-login></app-header-before-login>` components.
2. Use [ViewContainerRef.createComponent()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html)